# Spring boot with thymeleaf could not resolve view with name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm setting a spring boot project with thymeleaf but my view isn't displaying and getting the following error in the browser.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri May 24 00:44:22 GST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homePage() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

spring.application.name=Bootstrap Spring Boot
```

I had added thymeleaf feature in my html file, but when it wasn't working I just made it simple html file. My home.html is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello !</h1>
    <p>
        Welcome to Our App</span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a very simple and basic controller. I am not seeing any exception stack trace in the console.

Comment: do `return "index";` . And also add And also add `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`

Comment: @want2learn, about ```"index"``` sorry it was typo mistake. I have updated the question. I have added the recommended tag, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days of effort, I resolved this issue by downgrading spring boot version from 2.1.5 to

`<version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>`

Answer (score 0):

When you see this error , there are many possible reasons so try the following :

- Make sure that you folder structure is correct. When the maven folder structure is not followed , spring might have difficulties discovering endpoints etc.
- Make sure that you keep your main application.java a root package above other classes since spring boot annotation only scan the classes below your main class package.

For example :

```
com
   +- APP
         +- MainApplication.java  <--- your main class should be here, above your other classes
         |
         +- model
         |   +- model.java
         +- controller
             +- Controller.java
```

- Make sure that your resources are placed in the correct directory.

> By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called
>   `/static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources)` in the
>   classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.
>
> When you use one of these templating engines with the default
>   configuration, your templates are picked up automatically from
>   `src/main/resources/templates`.

Official doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html

Since, you have provided the thymeleaf configuration in the `application.yml`, you can put your thymeleaf templates in the `/templates` folder of your resources folder and spring should take it up.

Comment: I have double checked and all things are in place. Interestingly, I just downgraded my spring boot version to ```<version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>``` and it started working. Maybe there's some compatibility issue.

Comment: Oh, great will need to go through the changelist to find out what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

l have  a similar problem .l resolved it by renaming the home.html page to index.html and spring seems to resolve it automatically.Works like magic